# Como manipular onde o foco do VoiceOver do Iphone ira aparecer na tela seguinte quando a acessibilidade esta ativa?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, webview, acessibilidade

Tenho um problema de Acessibilidade apenas no Iphone, algumas paginas do APP são em Webview feitas em .aspx e essas telas usa uma estrutura de MultiView, ou seja uma unica pagina .aspx pode ter varias telas seguintes e são carregadas como se fosse um ajaxs. Ao clicar em um botão de avançar o conteúdo da tela seguinte é carregado e a marcação da acessibilidade continua no mesmo ponto da tela anterior que foi o botão de avançar por exemplo. Existe alguma forma de determinar onde o foco da acessibilidade tem que aparecer?

Comment: Cara, vale dar uma olhada em ARIA que é o que faz a parte de acessibilidade em web, imagino que o iPhone siga essa especificação. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, após muitas tentativa, acho que isso foi o que conseguimos ter um melhor resultado.
A ideia é usar o a **tabindex="-1"** e tag **role="status"**. É preciso seguir essa combinação pra funcionar.

```
     <script>
        function subirFoco() {
            if (navigator.platform.match(/iPhone|iPad/i)) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#foco').attr('tabindex', -1);
                    $('#foco').attr('role', 'status');
                    $('#foco').focus();
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    </script>
```